# How to merge two SQL rows (same item ID) with the SUM() qty but show only the last row's info?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was trying to use DISTINCT to show unique record, but not every column has same value.

[image]

Is there a way to merge my Count column's value of two rows that have the same UPC (item ID) but only show the 2nd (latest) info of the rest of the column like this?

[image]

Because my 'Unit Cost' has two different value, my DISTINCT function still produces two rows instead of just one.

If I just use TOP 1, then my Count value will not SUM both qty.

Would the OVER (Partition) or maybe UNION function work?

Thanks.

This is my current SQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 10
--1.UPC
CASE WHEN [UPC] IS NULL THEN ( 'Grand Total: ' ) + ' (' +(CONVERT(varchar(10), COUNT(DISTINCT [UPC]))) + ' unique items)'
ELSE [UPC]
END AS [UPC]

--2.ItemCode
,   CASE WHEN [ItemCode] IS NULL THEN ''
    ELSE [ItemCode] 
    END AS [Item Code]

--3.Vendor
,ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(30),[Vendor]),'') [Vendor#]

--4.MixMatch
,   CASE WHEN [MixMatch] IS NULL THEN ''
    ELSE [MixMatch] 
    END AS [Mix Match]

--5.Description
,   CASE WHEN [Description] IS NULL THEN ''
    ELSE [Description] 
    END AS [Description]

--6.CaseSize
,ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(5),[CaseSize]),'') [Case Size]

--7.Size
,ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(10),[Size]),'') [Size]

--8.Measure
,   CASE WHEN [Measure] IS NULL THEN ''
    ELSE [Measure] 
    END AS [Measure]

--9.Date Listed
,ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(20),[CreationDate]),'') [Date Listed]

--10.Case Cost
--,ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(20),[CaseCost]),'') [Case Cost]
,ISNULL( '$' + CONVERT(varchar(20),[CaseCost]),'') [Case Cost]

--11.Unit Cost
,ISNULL( '$' + CONVERT(varchar(20),[UnitCost]),'') [Unit Cost]

--14.Count
,CONVERT(int,ROUND(SUM([QtySold]),0)) AS [Count]

FROM [JS_Data].[dbo].[View_ItemMovement_TopSellers]
WHERE (UPC = '82983500006')
   AND (SaleDate BETWEEN '2013-05-01' AND '2014-05-01')

GROUP BY 
GROUPING SETS 
(
    ([UPC], [ItemCode], [Vendor], [MixMatch], [Description], [CaseSize], [Size],  [Measure], [CreationDate], [CaseCost], [UnitCost])
    ,()     
)
ORDER BY UPC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct in thinking of `partition by`; though you'll also need to use a join (or an inline SQL in the results).  Simplified example below:

```
select firstRow.id
, firstRow.upc
, firstRow.name
, sum(d.value) TotalUPCValue
from (
  select id, upc, name
  , row_number() over (partition by upc order by id) r
  from demo
) firstRow
inner join demo d on d.upc = firstRow.upc
where firstRow.r = 1
group by firstRow.id
, firstRow.upc
, firstRow.name
```

Working copy with table definition on SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6bfee/1

Here's the alternate version which doesn't use a join:

```
select id
, upc
, name
, (select sum(d.value) from demo d where d.upc = firstRow.upc) TotalUPCValue
from (
  select id, upc, name
  , row_number() over (partition by upc order by id) r
  from demo
) firstRow
where firstRow.r = 1
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6bfee/2

The first (join) method should typically be faster, but it's worth comparing against your data to confirm that.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @AndriyM for improving my second version:

```
select id
, upc
, name
, TotalUPCValue
from (
  select id, upc, name
  , row_number() over (partition by upc order by id) r
  , sum(value) over (partition by upc) as TotalUPCValue
  from demo
) firstRow
where firstRow.r = 1
;
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6bfee/7

Comment: Thank you, John. Could this be pre-configured in my View so my code could be simpler or I would still need to join my view with my original table?

Comment: Hey @Snow, I believe you should be able to add the column r to your view just by adding the line `, row_number() over (partition by upc order by IdOrSomeOtherColumn, OrHaveMultipleOrderByColumns) r`.  You could then make use of `r` in your above SQL to determine the first from the subsequent UPCs.

Comment: The alternate version could easily avoid the correlated subquery by calculating `SUM(value) OVER (PARTITION BY upc)` in the derived table.

Comment: Good shout @AndriyM.  Sadly the `value` column isn't available to the outer query since we're only selecting a subset of the data from `demo`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean but [this is what I was talking about](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6bfee/7) (see the second query).

Comment: @AndriyM Ah, I see, sorry I thought you were putting the partition by in line 4 in place of the sub query.  Revised code to match - thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out something,

if I change my Unit Cost column to

```
--11.Unit Cost
,ISNULL( '$' + CONVERT(varchar(20),max([UnitCost])),'') [Unit Cost]
```

and remove [Unit Cost] from my Group By clause,
i seem to get the output I want.